# How to enforce a static order for row_result diff list in ModelResource?

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using django-import-export module to import data from spreadsheet to my model via a ModelResource. After the instance initialization process and after the diff between the original and the imported object fields are calculated and a row result is generated, I want to be able to:

1) change the order of the headers in the html, which shows you the imported field values.

2) Add custom values for fields.

So far I have tried to override the after_import_row method in my ModelResource to tackle the problem stated in #2:

```py
    def after_import_row(self, row, row_result, **kwargs):
        diff = row_result.diff
        custom_value = 'Custom: {}'.format(row['Reason'])
        diff[2] = custom_value
```

I expect the third column header value of the HTML table to be changed to what I put in the step above. But since the header order is changed, I cannot ensure that the custom value is matching the header I want. That is why I want to enforce a static order for the diff headers in the row result.

How can I do this?